# .Net Core 2.1 Display Static JSON Files In Web Browser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a JSON file and want to view it directly in the web browser. when I attempt to access the file via its route it returns 404.

How can I view the JSON file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move the files inside of the `wwwroot` folder directory
2. Set the UseStaticFiles variable in your SetUp file

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
   {
       app.UseStaticFiles();
   }

[Referene Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1)